# Is there a text that provides the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, reference-request, math-history

I know that professor Andrew Wiles discovered his proof of Fermat's Last Theorem in 1995. One of my friends is looking for a text which provides his proof. I know that the proof is very complicated and uses difficult methods to get the solution, but I hope that you can give me the name of a text which contains it (or a link to the proof or such a text :)) I would also like to know what prerequisites are needed to study/understand the proof in detail? Furthermore, has anyone else discovered another proof since Wiles, or is Andrew Wiles' proof the only known solution?

thanks

Comment: [The Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wiles%27s_proof_of_Fermat%27s_Last_Theorem) cites *Andrew* Wiles's 1995 article "[Modular elliptic curves and Fermat's Last Theorem](http://dx.doi.org/10.2307%2F2118559)" in the Annals of Mathematics, 141 (3). [There is a PDF copy online.](http://math.stanford.edu/~lekheng/flt/wiles.pdf) You can also get a sense of the prerequisites from reading the Wikipedia article.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170142/knowledge-needed-to-understand-fermats-last-theorem-proof?rq=1

Comment: Wiles' proof was actually in June 1993; an erratum was seen in the September of that year. Wiles went away and published his full account of the Taniyama-Shimura Conjecture (or the Modularity Theorem) in September 1994.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

here http://math.stanford.edu/~lekheng/flt/wiles.pdf

no one else has proved it

Comment: The link is broken though.

Answer (score 5):

There are very few professional mathematicians who have read and understood all of Wiles proof. The pre-requisites go a long way beyond college level mathematics. Looking at Wiles paper is not a good way to learn about this problem.

If you're interested in number theory, you could begin by studying Hardy and Wright: "An introduction to theory of numbers". Some special cases of Fermat's last theorem were solved in the nineteenth century, and you should see their proofs in an introduction to algebraic number theory.

Comment: Hardy's book, I think, is not suitable for a beginner. It's writing is not of the best quality.

Answer (score 5):

The very minimal prerequisites for understanding the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem would include knowledge of algebraic number theory, modular forms, elliptic curves, Galois theory, Galois cohomology, and representation theory. A considerable amount of higher mathematics is needed to understand these areas in detail, including a very strong background in (advanced) abstract algebra. If/once you are comfortable with the necessary background material and are still interested in what I hear is a very good reference on the proof and its methods, check out ["Modular Forms and Fermat's Last Theorem"](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387989986) by Silverman, Stevens, and Cornell. The text is at intended for professional mathematicians, so it certainly won't be an easy read, but if one has a strong enough background and enough tenacity, one could certainly make it through. Reading and understanding this book would be a great help in making it through Wiles' proof. Good luck!