# What subjects should I learn to understand the proof of Fermat's Last Theorem?

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, modular-forms

My goal is to learn the math needed to understand all of Wiles's proof of Fermat's Last Theorem by the end of 2024.

Currently, I have a good understanding of calculus, differential equations, and linear algebra as well as bits and pieces of some other advanced math topics. I'm currently working through Niven's Introduction to Number Theory.

Could anyone please help me figure out a good roadmap for the subjects I should study to prepare me to understand the proof?

Comment: I doubt that you can do this in one year starting where you are.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [knowledge needed to understand Fermat's last theorem proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170142/knowledge-needed-to-understand-fermats-last-theorem-proof) - found in the list of RHS "Related" questions. Its answer says "If you have an understanding of these things at a graduate level (say a second or third year graduate student who is beginning research on these sorts of topics), then you will be able to understand the strategy of the proof and some aspects in more detail." Thus, as Ethan's comment states, you'll have trouble doing this in a year.

Comment: I dont' want to crush the new year's spirit and don't want to say it's impossible - but it's impossible. The three parts of math you named are freshman level courses and this proof is (see @JohnOmielan's comment) at least graduate level with a specification to algebraic geometry (one of the hardest branches of math) and others.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and the link.  The necessary knowledge does seem extensive. Let's say by 2034 to be safe :)

Comment: Conisder how difficult this problem was. The proof is extremely complicated , it took alone a year to repair an error in an earlier version. So, only extremely professional mathematicians will understand this proof at all , no matter how much time is invested.

Comment: I agree with Peter. Understanding the proof is not a matter of *time*. There are even people who do not understand that their own short proof (usually less than a page) is wrong, in their whole life.